# Allow WordPress users create it's own users and manage the content they can see

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, posts

I would like to create a website and I'm not sure if I'm able to do it on WordPress. On that website I would like to have two types of users. Let's call them doctors and patients. The doctors can create an account from the homepage level but the patient account can be created only by the doctors (two different user-registering forms, one on a website only for doctors, other one visible only after logging in from the doctor account - for creating a new patient). The website will have a lot of posts with different content.

**Q1. Is it possible that doctor could see all it's patients? And I mean only it's patients - so he can't see any other doctors and it's patients?**

**Q2. Is it possible that doctor could assign different posts for different patients? I.e. two-step user registering form - Step 1 - creating a username/pass for it's patient, Step 2 - a list view of all the posts on the website and a checkboxes on a side to check which posts that particular user/patient can see + a create new account button?**

All functions from the doctors account will be available after signing in to a paid membership.

Is it possible with WordPress? Is it super-duper complex? I've created tens of websites on WordPress but never worked with that complicated accounts.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks SO-brothers!

Comment: why do you want wp?

Comment: because that's the system I know, but I don't know if that's possible with it. any other recommendations?

Comment: Well I'm sure its possible but it will require a lot of hard work, I would recommend that you don't use Wp, just use simple languages, php,mysql, and ajax.